# How detect spacebar?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have a program in c++ where I have to detect spacebar, how can I do? I see that I need the function `getch()`, but in my program I haven´t `conio.h`. Exist other solution?

With `getchar` I need press `intro`, exist other form that I press only spacebar?

For example, can I introduce a `intro` without press `intro`???

Comment: what about [`getchar()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) or [`getc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/)?

Comment: @IrrationalPerson conio.h is *not* a standard C++ header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ans;
    do
    {
        //code
    }
    while(getchar() != 32 || getchar() != ' ');

   cout << "Space pressed" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

[Compiled Code](http://ideone.com/4aa4xV)

Windows.h:

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x80000000)
     MessageBox(NULL, "Spacebar pressed!", "TEST", MB_OK);
```

See no conio.h

Comment: If you see anything wrong, tell me

Comment: The main problem is line-buffering. You'd get `char(32)` only after hitting return. The second problem is `32`, which should be `'  '`.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson for one, you're missing semicolons. Have you tried to compile your solution?

Comment: What's the point of the final `if`? You won't leave the `while` loop until that condition is true.

Comment: I was compiling while you were commenting

Comment: But with `getchar` I need press `intro`, exist other form that I press only spacebar?

Comment: @Igor Please add this to your question

Comment: For example, can I introduce a enter without press enter???

Comment: @igor give me an example because your question has just become very confusing